# What does "error: invalid function declaration" mean?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-errors

With GCC 4.1.2, I get the error `tmp.cpp:8: error: invalid function declaration` for the following code

```
namespace edit {
  class A {
  public:
    void foo( );
  };
}

void edit:A::foo( ) {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was easy to fix:

```
void edit:A::foo( ) {
         ^
    missing ':'
```

should be:

```
void edit::A::foo( ) {
```

Comment: @STingRaySC: Questions with solutions are a good thing. This can only help and won't hurt anybody that comes later searching for that error message, so what good would it do to delete it?